# No Portfolio matches the given query in django 1.9.1

Tags: python, django

here is my code and I don't know where is my problem and I get this error:

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/portfolio/2016/02/03/home/
Raised by:  portfolio.views.post_detail
No Portfolio matches the given query.

here is my models.py

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    thumbnail= models.ImageField(upload_to='statics/thumbs/') 
    tags = TaggableManager()
    tour = models.URLField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('portfolio:post_detail',
                        args=[self.created.year,
                            self.created.strftime('%m'),
                            self.created.strftime('%d'),
                            self.slug])
```

here is my views.py

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Portfolio, slug=post,
                             created__year=year,
                             created__month=month,
                             created__day = day,)
    return render(request, 'portfolio/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

and my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list' ),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
 ]
```

Comment: You don't have a portfolio object with the given slug, and created date.

Comment: actually I have such object and in fact in another view(list view) this object can be found and rendered ...

Comment: "No Portfolio matches the given query.", the error is pretty clear. You might want to check the values of the inputs (year, month, day, post)

Comment: Also keep in mind your query translates to a SQL `AND`, rather than `OR`.  All four of your filter parameters must be true.

Comment: I check it several times and all parameters all true ...

Comment: It's obvious the problem is about your Portfolio query. Have you tried to debug the problem by yourself? Try to print out all the vars you pass and check if they are the same as you expect. Also you can try to exclude slug field from your query. If it solves the problem, your slug and post is not equal for some reason.